# Edit Content Security Policy in onHeadersReceived

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a small chrome extension for myself to embed an iframe into the website. Content Security Policy makes this difficult, since the frame-src directive on a few websites doesn't allow my content to be loaded.
The error message is the following:

> Refused to frame 'mydomain' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src someotherdomain".

So far, I have tried adding my host to the frame-src directive and to the frame-ancestors in webRequest.onHeadersReceived.

Permissions in the `manifest.json` are the following:

```
    "permissions": ["contextMenus", "webRequest", "<all_urls>", "tabs", "webRequestBlocking"],
```

Editing the headers in the `background.js`:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    editCSPHeader,
    {
        urls: [ "<all_urls>" ],
        types: [ "sub_frame" ]
    },
    ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]
  );

function editCSPHeader(r) {
    const headers = r.responseHeaders; // original headers
    for (let i=headers.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
        let header = headers[i].name.toLowerCase();
        if (header === "content-security-policy") { 
            headers[i].value = headers[i].value.replace("frame-src", "frame-src https://*.mydomain.xy/*");
        }
    }
    return {responseHeaders: headers};
}
```

After the iframe still not being loaded properly, I did a capture using chrome://net-export. Here the headers showed up as unmodified, even though they should be edited.

Comment: You can embed an iframe that points to your own extension html page (listed in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) of course), where you can embed an iframe with that other site. No need for webRequest's fragile header manipulation that fails when other extensions modify the headers.

Comment: If you want to embed your iframe into the main frame, you need to change the CSP header in the main frame. Change `types: [ "sub_frame" ]` in your code above to `types: [ "main_frame" ]` to do that.

Comment: Changing the type from `sub_frame` to `main_frame` indeed solved this issue.

Comment: Since my comment seems to have solved the issue, I am posting it as an answer as suggested [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The sources from which you can load iframes are restricted by the CSP of their parent frame.**

**If you want to embed your iframe into the main frame, you need to change the CSP header in the main frame. Change `types: [ "sub_frame" ]` in your code above to `types: [ "main_frame" ]` to do that.**

Also please note that manipulation of headers using `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived` is not very reliable. Only one extension at a time can modify them, so other extensions that do so may break your extension.